# How do I set KMPlayer to "fit player to video on start"?

Tags: kmplayer

I am new to KMPlayer and can't find the setting that resizes the application screen to the video's 100% size.  Windows Media Player has "Fit Player to Video on Start", VLC has "resize interface to video size" and Media Player Classic has "Auto zoom to 100%".  Can KMPlayer do this?

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the interface, and Screen Controls --> Start Playback In --> Original Size.

There's also Screen Controls --> Keep Video Frame To --> Normal Size (100%).

Answer (score 1):

1- On KMP screen click F2 , Preferences window will show up , 
2- Down the Preferences  window click on (Reset current Preset) 
3- close and re-open the KMP player again and everything will back to normal size

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Go to Screen Controls → Keep Video Frame To → Window Size (Default)
2. Then, when playing video, go to fullscreen (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>).

   - Alternatively, go to fullscreen overscan (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>).
3. Also, you can add adjustment: Screen Controls → Start Plyback In → Fullscreen (Normal).